# In spite of you doing this

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

Is using this phrase in such a structure acceptable? (Just like "instead of somebody doing something".)

> I won the game **in spite of you making** an effort to stop me.

Comment: _I won the game despite your efforts to stop me._

Answer (score 1):

This would definitely be acceptable in conversation. However, a grammar pedant might say that the possessive is required there:

- I won the game **in spite of your** making an effort to stop me.

On the other hand, this might sound awkward in informal contexts.
To get the best of both possibilities, you might consider this:

- I won the game in **spite of your** efforts at stopping me.

Comment: Wow, a downvote? I thought downvotes were supposed to be reserved for  answers that just didn't satisfy the requirements of the question.

Comment: Must be a grammar pedant amidst... :p